# How to push data into array inside a pop up (pop up opens for particular id) using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I successfully added data to array using push method normally but failed to do so inside a pop up which opens up for a particular Id . 
Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-3" for="pwd">Speciality:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">  
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="spec" id="usr">
      <button type="submit" ng-click="addSpeciality()">Add </button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">

    <ul>
       <li ng-repeat="spec in speciality">
          {{ spec }}
          <button  ng-click="removeSpeciality($index)">Remove</button>
       </li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.speciality=[];

$scope.addSpeciality = function(){
   $scope.speciality.push($scope.spec);
   $scope.spec = ''; 
};

$scope.removeSpeciality = function(index) {
   $scope.speciality.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: What is `$scope.spec`? It does not seem to be defined. You need to share some more code of controller

Comment: @sami https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: Thanks @pszaba for your interest but i could get nothing about my question. I think in given code `$scope.spec` really needs to be told about

Answer (score 0):

This is point when you need a `Factory`. Forget about storing any data in controllers. Really - **FORGET!** The only proper way to share data across application is to define `Factory` you like and inject it separately in every place you gonna work with that data.

You should not store data in `$scope`. `$scope` itself is an instance bind to DOM element. So only way you access any data from any level of deepness is using `$parent` what is a great mistake.

Your controller should `$inject` that `Factory` and call related methods when you need to change anything in data. Never pass business logic in controllers. They are like Strategy design pattern - place where you only tell what business logic should take place when you got trigger (click for example):

```
SpecialityFactory.addSpeciality = function () {
  SpecialityFactory.specialities.push({});
}

SpecialityFactory.removeSpeciality = function (idx) {
  SpecialityFactory.specialities.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

So it will be much easier to share business logic across your controllers:

```
// PageController
PageController.prototype.addSpeciality = function () {
  SpecialityFactory.addSpeciality();
};

PageController.$inject = ['SpecialityFactory'];

// ModalController
ModalController.prototype.removeSpeciality = function (idx) {
  SpecialityFactory.removeSpeciality(idx);
};

ModalController.$inject = ['SpecialityFactory'];
```

Comment: What is wrong in storing data in controller , sorry I am new to angular.

Comment: You are new to Software Development if you ask why **Business Logic** should be separated from **Controllers**. It is done for keeping your code supportable, where all data manipulations for exact types (it your case specialties) is encapsulated in only one `Factory` instead of be smeared across all code. You will be always sure that this data can be modified within one place, and if you encounter bug related to it, you will have only 1 place to look for it, instead of searching across all your files.

Comment: Oh right !! Thanks for sharing , I will try to use factory for this . Is it possible to use same factory of specialities  for different fields like for example degrees,phone numbers,alternate addresses etc.

Comment: You can encapsulate dedicated properties in models. Example (degrees,phone numbers,alternate addresses) looks like `UserFactory` or `PeopleFactory`, where each user is instance of `class User()`.

Comment: In general - you should separate place where you only use data for display propose from places where you manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all @Apperion is right, read his answer 
but to get your code working try to add the controller to your wrapper HTML element

```
<div class="form-group" ng-controller="ExampleController">
```

and

with this array your ng-repeat won't work this way, you need to use this way:

```
<li ng-repeat="spec in speciality track by $index">
```